# Snapping to specific grid positions

Tags: xna

I have a grid system laid out that lets me to snap objects to the grid, and that works perfectly fine, but it's not the behavior I'm looking for in this situation. I couldn't for the life of me put this into words that would make any sense (probably why I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it...) so I figure a picture with the current behavior and expected behavior will do a much better job:

[image: grid]

The left hand side shows the current behavior (note: the grid system is actually twice as big as the white grid lines shown above. This allows objects to be placed on the grid lines, which is the intended behavior I'm looking for.)

The right hand side is how I want objects to snap to the grid. I only want objects to be placed on the grid lines, not on the grid nodes (or the blank center node).

In the expected behavior, objects will ALWAYS snap to the grid if the paired value is opposite of it -- if X is ODD, then the Y value must be EVEN for it to snap or vice-versa (i.e. [0, 1], [1, 0], [2,3]). Objects won't snap to [0,0], [1,1], [4, 2] because they're both ODD or both EVEN. Just something I noticed that was consistent with the behavior I was looking for but couldn't translate this into anything useful.

Here's the snap to grid code in it's entirety:

```
//Grab the mouse state
MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();

//TileX = (int)Math.Floor((float)(mouse.X / tileWidth));  //tileWidth = 80
//TileY = (int)Math.Floor((float)(mouse.Y / tileHeight)); //tileHeight = 80

//We want "snap to closest grid space" instead of "snap to next-lowest grid space", 
//like the Math.Floor code does above. The ".ToInt()" extensions simply rounds a 
//float to the closest integer. i.e. 2.2 = 2     2.5 = 3    3 = 3
TileX = ((float)mouse.X / tileWidth).ToInt();
TileY = ((float)mouse.Y / tileHeight).ToInt();

//Set the square to a whole tile coordinate
squarePosition.X = TileX * tileWidth;
squarePosition.Y = TileY * tileHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit trickier than it seems like it should be because how you snap in the x depends on how you snap in the y (and vise verse).  I think the way I'd do it is to first figure out which square you are in using the code you posted above with a 2x tileHeight and tileWidth.  Once you have the square that your point is within, you can use some if conditions to figure out which edge the mouse is closest to.

Actually, I suppose you could also derive a closed form solution by rotating your points 45 degrees around the origin, snapping them as you do in your code above, and then rotating the snapped positions back (45 degrees in the other direction).

Whichever makes more sense to you...  Best!